# How to do a select query for a column having more than 225 character?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to select a column value from a table in SQL Server.

1. Column has more than 225 characters
2. When I am using a simple select query (`select ecomment from comment`), the output is truncated at 225th character.

How is it possible to get an un-truncated value for that column?

Comment: Most likely the value has been truncated on save, since the maximum characters you can store in that column is 225.

Comment: no, column can store data upto 5000 character, and data is there more than 225 character in database, but output is truncating at 225th character.

Comment: Ok, then I assume @JamesZ s answer might be the solution. I've never heard about this before.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're having this issue with Management Studio? There are 2 settings for maximum text length, separate for text and grid output in Query Results -> SQL Server -> "Results to Grid" and "Results to Text".

You can find detailed information in [Martin Bell's blog post](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/martinbell/archive/2009/10/25/How-to-display-long-text-in-SSMS.aspx)

Comment: Thanks James, i will try this option also and will post here.